# Qt creator fails while gedit work perfectly : Encoding issue

Tags: qt, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, qt5

In gedit and sublime it looks 
Name[dv]=މިސާލުތަށް

In Qt creator I can only see square boxes

I'm using UTF8 in all editors. Why Qt creator fails to detect certain characters.

I have product based on QPlainTextEdit where problem exactly same as Qt creator that's why I want to dig deep. Its confirmed file is UTF8 using sublime.
[image]

Update:
Same font for both editors
Its doesn't look version problem. Although I need to confirm on this part.

This is standard file on all ubuntu. example.desktop

Comment: May be there is a font problem? Try to use the same font in all editors.

Comment: Are you using Qt 5.3 by any chance? It possibly got broken in this regard. If you see the same problem in Qt 5.2, then we'd need to see a binary sample of the file you're opening. You can minimize it to one line, and add as a hex dump to your question.

Comment: That's clearly not the same font in both editors.  Look at the lower-case letter i, for example.